# Android disable recyclerview vertical scroll up expanding the bottomsheet

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I have the following layout which I include in a coordinator layout and provide bottomsheet behavior to it. I set peek height of this bottomsheet as 60%. When I scroll up the recyclerview, the bottomsheet expands. I do not want the bottomsheet to expand/collapse until user drags it manually. How can I achieve this behavior. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="40dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/image"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: This project helped: https://github.com/laenger/BottomSheetCoordinatorLayout

Comment: This related answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62539418/4916458